# Recover an oracle cluster node

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, clone, ocr, database-administration

I have an oracle RAC enviroment with 4 servers. One of the servers crashed and i recovered it using a mirror disk from one of the other 3 machines of the rac.

Now, the recovered machine, can't join the oracle cluster, however i count with a full backup of the system.

it's possible to "restore" the node, simply replacing the oracle installation with the one from the full backup? (home,grid, etc...)

Or if have to take out the node from the cluster, clone from another machine an rejoin it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I would run the removeNode.sh and addNode.sh commands to get things back in order. That's the safest way of getting your cluster working properly.